# asyncio version of `os.chmod` in Python

Tags: python, chmod, python-asyncio

I have some Python3 code running inside an `asyncio` event loop.

I want to use the functionality of `os.chmod(...)`, but would ideally like a non-blocking version of this, so that I can use `await os.chmod(...)`, and avoid making a blocking system call.

I don't believe there any libraries available that supply this functionality yet, at least from what I can see.

How would I go about implementing a non-blocking `os.chmod(...)` from scratch? Better still, is there a pre-existing solution?

Comment: For context, I'm implementing a Gunicorn worker process, that uses asyncio. Gunicorn uses a spinning `fchmod` status for signalling worker process aliveness. https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/workertmp.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UNIX systems have not implemented an asynchronous API for the `chmod` syscall.
Thus the best you can do is run it in a thread pool:

```
await loop.run_in_executor(None, os.chmod, fname, mode)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `await loop.run_in_executer(None, os.chmod, fname, mode)`?

Comment: @YuvalPruss Did you mean `await loop.run_in_executor(None, os.chmod, fname, mode)`? ;)